# How to modify the params in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller has to modify the session_id before saving the information.

```
user.rb
    has_one :room

class Room < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

Rooms_controller.rb

```
n_room = room_params
    n_room[:room][:session_id] = session.session_id
    respond_to do |format|
      binding.pry
      if current_user.create_room(params[:n_room])
        format.html { redirect_to '/rooms/#{@new_room.id}'}
```

But this is not working, the session_id is not stored in the rooms row.

Question 1:
How to modify 'rooms_params'?
Question 2:
How to pass it to rooms model in the line 'current_user.create_room'?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define in this way

```
def create
  params[:room][:session_id] = 1
  respond_to do |format|
    if current_user.create_room(room_params)
      format.html { redirect_to '/rooms/', notice: 'Room was successfully created.' }
   else
     format.html { render :new }
   end
end

def room_params
  params.require(:room).permit(:name, :type, :session_id)
end
```

Comment: That seems to work except that the insert into statement is not storing the 'session_id' and 'name' value to the "Room" table. Do you the reason? INSERT INTO "rooms" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2018-12-25 17:18:14.300732"], ["updated_at", "2018-12-25 17:18:14.300732"], ["user_id", 6]] Thanks

Comment: Rooms table has all "session_id" and "name" column:

Comment: It worked! I gave `current_user.create_room(params[room_params])` instead of `current_user.create_room(room_params)`

Comment: That is an example for your questions but those attribute i decalred inside for my room model. First u need to declare in your db. If u liked my question than please accept the answer

Comment: You can follow this links for strong params https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: Declared the `Room` model right. The main difference is passing the parameter as `params[room_params]` and `room_params` to `create_room`. What is the difference between these 2? Thanks so much for your answers!

Comment: If you passed directly params[room_params] in your create action means you are allowing some one can update whole room object if u want after creation of room object in update action only specific attribute will allow to update You can follow this links for strong params https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html